# How to set Textillate script manually?

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I'm using [Textillate.js](https://github.com/jschr/textillate) to animate one sentense and I'm not really sure how to set out animation manually. After clicking a button the text should come in in animated form. And it works fine:

```
$( "#my_button" ).click(function() {   
$('#my_text').textillate({loop: false, initialDelay: 200, in: {effect: 'bounceInLeft'}});
$('#my_text').addClass('show');
});
```

And now I want this text to dissapear by using out animation. I tried like this:

```
$( "#my_2_button" ).click(function() {   
$('#my_text').textillate({loop: false, out: {effect: 'bounceOutLeft'}});
});
```

and it doesn't work. Do you have any ideas?

CSS:

```
`#my_text {
opacity: 0;
}

.show {
opacity: 1!important;
}`
```

Comment: Why you add !important in class `show`? It will override the css from this plugin

Comment: It overwrites the basic opacity of #my_text. Without it #my_text remains invisible.

Comment: You can remove class `show` when click to `#my_2_button`. `$('#my_text').removeClass('show');`

Comment: I did as you said and as result #my_text disappears suddenly - without any animation. It's because opacity of it becomes 0 again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with given method. They are at the bottom of the page.
In your case it's `$element.textillate('out')`